# where do I find page source of pages on my system which I opened in Chrome and then Closed

Tags: macos, google-chrome, temp

I was working on a blog page and by mistake deleted most of my work and then closed the tab. Now I'm trying to sneak into my MAC to find some temp files in which Chrome might be storing the source of fetched pages. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

it should be at

```
 ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome.
```

good luck digging there :S

this issue of loosing files was fixed years ago, learn how to use git

http://try.github.io/

Comment: blogger should start using git